# Add <tr> after every second <td> using

Tags: php, jquery, tr

I have PHP code which fetching images from database with `<td>` tags. I would like to display two pictures in row, any advice how to add `<tr>` after every second `<td>` using jQuery?

```
public function homepage_gall($panel){

    //Fetching photos from database,to create photo gallery called in homepage.php
    $sql="SELECT name FROM photos LIMIT 6";
    $this->query($sql);

    while($row=$this->result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $this->name=$row['name'];

    // Making different path,depends on place where function is called,panel.php or homepage.php
        if($panel){

        echo "<td><img src=\"../uploaded_images/".$this->name."\"/></td>";
                }
        else{


        echo "<td><img src=\"uploaded_images/".$this->name."\"/></td>";

         }
        }
   }
```

Comment: If you're generating the td tags with PHP, why not generate the tr tags in PHP as well?  Unless you need to dynamically change the td tags around, there's no need to set up the rows in the browser.

Comment: Do you have access to this source php?   Ideally, you should use a floated or div-based structure and format it responsively with css on the front end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you want to use jQuery on this but I would add a table and handle all tr and td in PHP as you already do. Replace your whole code with the following if you want that:

```
public function homepage_gall($panel) {
    //Fetching photos from database,to create photo gallery called in homepage.php
    $sql = "SELECT name FROM photos LIMIT 6";
    $this->query($sql);
    echo '<table><tr>';
    $i = 0;
    while ($row = $this->result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $i++;
        $this->name=$row['name'];
        // Making different path,depends on place where function is called,panel.php or homepage.php
        if ($i % 2 === 0) {
            echo '</tr><tr>';
        }
        if ($panel) {
            echo "<td><img src=\"../uploaded_images/".$this->name."\"/></td>";
        } else {
            echo "<td><img src=\"uploaded_images/".$this->name."\"/></td>";
        }
    }
    echo '</tr></table>';
}
```